# wxPython StyledTextCtrl high CPU usage

Tags: python, wxpython, scintilla

Today, while working on my project, I noticed that when i move my caret in wxStyledTextCtrl, my CPU usage jumps up to 84%! Does anyone now what may be causing the problem? I am using code from wxPython StyledTextCtrl example. Running Fedora 18 x64.